# How to remove whitespace of empty <select> in IE

Tags: html, css

Below are screenshots I took on an empty `<select>` in IE8 and Chrome.
What happens is that when a `<select>` element is empty, IE8 still shows a long dropdown but with just whitespaces while Chrome shows nothing (which is what I want too in IE).

Any ideas for this?

P.S. I can't add dummy `<option>` for this.

[image: empty select in IE and other browsers]

Comment: Looks like you have added a height to select: is that correct ?

Comment: So your saying you cannot add a default dummy option? Why exactly? If I were you, I would just add: `selected="selected"` for the option you want to be the default

`<option selected="selected">Pick an Option</option>`

Comment: @AdityaSaxena nope, no height was set sir.
Shivam, basically I want a "select-looking" input (with arrowdown at the right) but no options. Although I can freely make a custom input for this, I just wanted to recycle plain old <select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by inserting a empty option or optgroup like this

```
<select><optgroup></optgroup></select>
```

or

```
<select><option></option></select>
```

or as @Shivam you could do this as this

```
<select><option selected="selected">Pick an Option</option>
```

But you mentioned you don't need dummy option. But the browser behaves you mentioned in your question by default.

Comment: hi sir, I can't seem to make this work (the jQuery solution), it still shows whitespaces.

Can you perhaps show a screenshot sir? in IE? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Though I gave up on this approach and made a select-looking <input> instead :D